# Containment and UITableView flashScrollIndicators

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I currently have a Parent ViewController which contains a child UIViewController (Child).  The child UIViewController has a UITableView.  On Child.viewDidAppear I invoke the TableView.flashScrollIndicators.

For some reason the scroll indicators are not flashing.  I've noticed if I put a dispatch_after call, the second pass does a flash.  I thought at first it was a size issue, but I don't think that's it. It seems to be a layout issue (I'm using Storybards, iOS 7, and no AutoLayout).  Any ideas?

Here's my code for creating the Child.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add it to the heirarchy
    if ([[self childViewControllers] count] == 0) {
        [self setViewControllers:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

        ProductSelectionViewController *destination = (ProductSelectionViewController *)[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductSelectionViewController"];

        [self addChildViewController:destination];

        // present the child
        [destination didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [[self containerView] addSubview:[destination view]];

        [[self viewControllers] addObject:destination];

        [destination setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it worked to call

```
[self performSelector: @selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];
```

instead of

```
[self flashScrollIndicators];
```

in `didMoveToWindow` method of the view or in `viewDidAppear` of its view controller. Hope this helps people with the same issue.